# SQL select row count by unique ID group by range

Tags: sql

Given that I have the following two tables:

```
User
-------
UserID



UserLikes
----------
UserID
OtherUserID
```

When a user likes another user, the user performing the like gets stored as UserID and the user receiving the like gets stored as OtherUserID.

How can I get a distribution showing a count of how many users that have given:

0 likes

1-10 likes

11-50 likes

51-100 likes

101 + likes

Comment: Have you tried anything?  Please edit your question and show your attempt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example, people that liked between 1 and 10:

```
SELECT T.userID,count(*) as TotalLikes
FROM UserLikes t
GROUP BY T.userID
HAVING COUNT(*) between 1 and 10
```

To change the range, just change the having clause

```
HAVING COUNT(*) = 0
HAVING COUNT(*) between 1 and 10
HAVING COUNT(*) between 11 and 50
HAVING COUNT(*) between 51 and 100
HAVING COUNT(*) > 100
```

If you meant you want the results to be:

```
0 likes | 1-10 likes | ....
   3          5         ....
```

Then:

```
SELECT sum(case when TotalLikes = 0 then 1 else 0 end) as No_Likes,
SELECT sum(case when TotalLikes between 1 and 10 then 1 else 0 end) as One_To_ten_likes,
SELECT sum(case when TotalLikes between 11 and 50 then 1 else 0 end) as Eleven_To_Fifty_Likes,
.......
FROM(
    SELECT T.userID,count(*) as TotalLikes
    FROM UserLikes t
    GROUP BY T.userID)
```